# How to create a slide menu, with multiple/different tab views in xcode 7, iOS9?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I am struggling to create an app which consists of a slide out menu, as well as multiple tabbed views once the user has clicked on a menu item.

Basically the app is a tutorial app - the different menu items will be the different sections, and each section has multiple sub-sections that i would like the user to be able to scroll through in a tabbed fashion. Example: Menu item: 'Cooking' - and when user clicks on it I want him/her to be able to scroll through tabs such as 'baking', 'barbeque' and 'fried food' etc.

What is the best way to do this? So far I have successfully created a slideout menu using a swRevealController, also the slideout menu enables me to navigate to different view controllers when I click a menu Item.

Now what would be the best way to add some subsections?

Ultimately I want to create an iOS equivalent of an android 'drawer with swipe tabs'.

Currently my storyboard looks like this. How do I add multiple views (accessed via tabs) for each menu item?

[image]

Comment: Check this demo https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sidemenuswiftdemo

Answer (score 1):

Simple method is to subclass UITableViewController.
Setup your different cells and then override didSelectRowAtIndexPath, example :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
    case 0:
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginScreen", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController!
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
        break;
    case 1:
        //calling popup
        let SB = UIStoryboard(name: "PopUpStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let controller = SB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("aboutPopup")
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // discard menu
        self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true)
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

A popup would usually be displayed on mainscreen so you discard the slideout menu, a regular view is just presented on top of it.

Comment: Thanks! I have done what you have said - But I have refactored my code and also added each menu item to its own story board.

Now the problem is that when I try and pan to get the slide out menu to come in, it gives me this error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


This occurs when I try and call the pan gesture recognizer method in any of the first view controllers the menu takes me to after the first go:

  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

This may be nooby but this has really gotten me stuck :/

Comment: The problem is probably coming from a deallocated variable, with arc once your leave the scope a variable who isn't put at class scope might be nil if there is no strong reference.
Taking the sample of code you could instantiate the controller at the top of the class and that could solve the problem (happened to me on something similar.
If you haven't i suggest you to read the official documentation on it :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: I misread your comment, i thought this was about the controllers in the menu.
But the issue is the same, a lost reference, check your connections in the storyboard or the references in your code

Comment: Could it not be because the views are opened modally using your method - and so have to be dismissed, rather than recalling the menu on top again?

Comment: SWRevealController is nil in the next storyboard?:/

Comment: Yes it could be, you could go back to the main view using :
        func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
        {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController!
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

Oherwise you could push your view on top of the current view to prevent that but i personnaly prefer to go back to the tab view instead of the slide out.